# Get average of last 4 cells Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to figure out how to find the average of the last 4 columns. Every column in yellow `Fame` is the score, and then `Attacks` is how many attacks used to get that score.

So essentially, it would need to add up the last 4 `Fame` columns, and divide it by the sum of the last 4 `Attacks` columns.

**Example**

For the first row (row 3), the final output would do this calculation:

(3500+2700+3250+3300) / (16+12+16+16) = **212.5**

**Example 2**

For the second row (row 4), the final output would do this calculation:

(2850+3500) / (16+16) = **198.4**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what about row 4?

Comment: @player0, just added another example for row 4. thanks!

Comment: by "last 4 columns" you mean from right or from left? coz your example 1 is from left and example 2 is wrong coz 2850 and 3500 are apart 5 columns not 4

Comment: @player0 from left to right. by "last 4 columns", i simply mean up to the last 4 columns with values. so if they're empty just ignore them. i hope that clarifies, thanks for the help.

Comment: when a row has 5 values and you want the values to include the first column then this is the FIRST 4 values.. the last 4 values would exclude the first value and include the last value.

Comment: @player0 thank you a lot. one more thing, is it possible to sort the spreadsheet by column C? when i do it messes it up slightly

Comment: @MrShane yes, but these are the 4 most recent scores. that's why I said "last"

Comment: possible but like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VaOuB5ClN-3CxHiNU7mP8sLxCl4dmoE8UULXhEwYfU8/edit#gid=360595443

Comment: @player0 gotcha, I assumed there would be a way to have the formula only worry about it's own row. and then copy the formula to all of the rows and sort them. right now it seems like 1 cell is finding the average for all rows, and that seems to be causing the issue. is it possible to do on a row-to-row basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from right to left try:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, FILTER(D3:3, 
 MOD(COLUMN(D3:3), 2)=0)), "\d+ \d+ \d+ \d+$"), " "))/
 SUM(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, FILTER(D3:3, 
 MOD(COLUMN(D3:3)-1, 2)=0)), "\d+ \d+ \d+ \d+$"), " "))
```

[image]

---

### update:

from left to right use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(D3:6),,9^9))), " ")*1), 
 "select (Col1+Col3+Col5+Col7)/(Col2+Col4+Col6+Col8)"), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: hey, this outputs 202.5 for me. do you know why? I will add another example, maybe I didn't explain it clearly.

Comment: @Apehk (3250+3300+2900+3500)/(16+16+16+16)=202.34375

Comment: it's (3500+2700+3250+3300) / (16+12+16+16) = 212.5

Comment: @Apehk answer updated

Comment: @Apehk https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sFcLB1sa-fbWvNLR6OqR0-eWe4fYjq6SD-yYUqckMAE/edit#gid=0

Comment: hey, i got it to work for some of the rows. but it returns an error for many others. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RXZ-RfT3XwDEHeTCFnfDdSx-REt73cP7GN0Ao_MANjY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Apehk this is how you use it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VaOuB5ClN-3CxHiNU7mP8sLxCl4dmoE8UULXhEwYfU8/edit#gid=1796939298